# How to move a different activity on recycler view click?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I want to move to different activity when I click any of the recycler view. But when I'm clicking on any of them it is going to the same activity

```java
ArrayList<FeaturedHelperClass> featuredLocations = new ArrayList<>();

featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.auditorium_a, "Mahatma Gandhi Auditorium", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));
featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.auditorium_a, "Nethaji Auditorium", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));
featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.auditorium_a, "V.O.C. Auditorium", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));
featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.audtiorium_b, "Conference Room - AB", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));
featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.audtiorium_b, "RUBY (Admin Block)", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));
featuredLocations.add(new FeaturedHelperClass(R.drawable.smart_classroom, "Smart Class", "It is a long established fact that a reader."));

adapter = new FeaturedAdapter(featuredLocations, this);
featuredRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to adapter class at under `onBindViewHolder` create `holder.view.setOnClickListener`

For example:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {

                Intent reminderActivity = new Intent(view.getContext(), CoinReminderActivity.class);
                reminderActivity.putExtra(Constants.COIN_NAME, currencies.getCoinName().toLowerCase());
                view.getContext().startActivity(reminderActivity);

    });
```